# How to generate list of column names from Dataframe if row value =1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Data frame in the following format

```
CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3 CLASS 4 CLASS 5 CLASS 6 CLASS 7 CLASS 8 CLASS 9 CLASS 10    CLASS 11 CLASS 12   CLASS 13    CLASS 14    CLASS 15    CLASS 16    CLASS 17    CLASS E CLASS V
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
8944    0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
8945    1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
8946    0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
8947    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8948    0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

I want to get a list for each row, such that the list contains the names of columns in row.

For example for 1st row in data, I want to return list as
`['CLASS 3', 'CLASS 7']`
for 2nd row , `['CLASS 3', 'CLASS 6','CLASS 7','CLASS 8','CLASS 16','CLASS V']` 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is MultIndex with one level only use:

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([( 'CLASS 1',),
            ( 'CLASS 2',),
            ( 'CLASS 3',),
            ( 'CLASS 4',),
            ( 'CLASS 5',),
            ( 'CLASS 6',),
            ( 'CLASS 7',),
            ( 'CLASS 8',),
            ( 'CLASS 9',),
            ('CLASS 10',),
            ('CLASS 11',),
            ('CLASS 12',),
            ('CLASS 13',),
            ('CLASS 14',),
            ('CLASS 15',),
            ('CLASS 16',),
            ('CLASS 17',),
            ( 'CLASS E',),
            ( 'CLASS V',)],
           )


df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

If there are only `1` and `0` values in data use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['new'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
```

Or filter per rows:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x == 1].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), fitler by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last create `list` per groups:

```
df['new'] = (df.stack()
               .reset_index(name='val')
               .query('val == 1')
               .groupby('level_0')['level_1']
               .apply(list))
```

Comment: The great @jezrael replied. Thanks for the reply. However, i am getting the following output. ``` 
0                                [(CLASS 3,), (CLASS 7,)]

1       [(CLASS 3,), (CLASS 6,), (CLASS 7,), (CLASS 8,...

2        [(CLASS 3,), (CLASS 5,), (CLASS 7,), (CLASS 9,)]

3        [(CLASS 2,), (CLASS 3,), (CLASS 7,), (CLASS 8,)]

4                    [(CLASS 3,), (CLASS 7,), (CLASS V,)]
. I would have needed something like,

['CLASS 3','CLASS 7'] and so on.

Comment: @AdityaVartak - Waht is `print (df.columns)` before my solution?

Comment: didnt understand your question

Comment: @AdityaVartak - Can you test `print (df.columns)` and past output to question? Because seems there is multiindex, but not sure

Comment: yes youre right, its multi index. 
MultiIndex([( 'CLASS 1',),
            ( 'CLASS 2',),
            ( 'CLASS 3',),
            ( 'CLASS 4',),
            ( 'CLASS 5',),
            ( 'CLASS 6',),
            ( 'CLASS 7',),
            ( 'CLASS 8',),
            ( 'CLASS 9',),
            ('CLASS 10',),
            ('CLASS 11',),
            ('CLASS 12',),
            ('CLASS 13',),
            ('CLASS 14',),
            ('CLASS 15',),
            ('CLASS 16',),
            ('CLASS 17',),
            ( 'CLASS E',),
            ( 'CLASS V',)],
           )
but need one only

Comment: Also your 3rd query, 
df['new'] = df.stack().reset_index(name='val').query('val == 1').groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(list) doesnt work because there is no val

Comment: @AdityaVartak - Can you add before my solution `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)` ?

Comment: yes that worked like a charm, but how to remove Multi-index columns as it is not needed i think

Comment: @AdityaVartak - Not sure if understand - `but how to remove Multi-index columns as it is not needed i think `

Comment: I meant that i dont think i need multi-index columns, hence how to remove them.